# Multiple inner joins with filter in Laravel 5 Eloquent query efficieny

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following models and relations:
Ads has many-to-many with Cities
Ads has many-to-many with Categories

Now I want to get Ads for a specific City and specific Category.  So in SQL I do the following and getting the correct result:

```
select * from ads
inner join ad_cities on ad_cities.adId = ads.id
inner join ad_categories on ad_categories.adId = ads.id
where ad_cities.cityId = 1525
and ad_categories.categoryId = 6
```

I know it can be done using DB:table(xxxx)->join->....
But I want to know if the same can be done on the model without taking the DB:table approach.

I tried the following and getting the result, but the query generated doesn't seem to be efficient.

```
return Category::find(6)
            ->ads()
            ->whereHas('cities', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('cityId', '=', '1525');
                    })                    
            ->where('statusName', '=', 'PUBLISHED')
            ->orderBy('publishedAt', 'DESC')
            ->simplePaginate($pageSize);
```

This generated the following query:

```
select `ads`.*, `ad_categories`.`categoryId` as `pivot_categoryId`, `ad_categories`.`adId` as `pivot_adId` from `ads` inner join `ad_categories` on `ads`.`id` = `ad_categories`.`adId` where `ad_categories`.`categoryId` = '6' and (select count(*) from `cities` inner join `ad_cities` on `cities`.`id` = `ad_cities`.`cityId` where `ad_cities`.`adId` = `ads`.`id` and `cityId` = '1525') >= 1 and `statusName` = 'PUBLISHED' order by `publishedAt` desc limit 16 offset 0
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks,
Velu

Answer (score 0):

I've spent quite some time banging my head against this one in my own projects, and the best I can some up with is this:

```
return Category::find(6)
            ->ads()
            ->join('ad_cities', 'ad_cities.adId', '=', 'ads.id')
            ->where('ad_cities.cityId', 1525)                   
            ->where('statusName', '=', 'PUBLISHED')
            ->orderBy('publishedAt', 'DESC')
            ->simplePaginate($pageSize);
```

It's something, right? It gives you the right SQL and preserves the Eloquent API to some extent. The other thing I've been doing, with queries that I couldn't even shoehorn into this, is using [`hydrate`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) and [`hydrateRaw`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrateRaw) after fetching with raw SQL.

This way, when someday I figure out how to use Eloquent effectively and/or Eloquent matures, the interface between Model and Controller will still be right and I can just replace the SQL with ORM goodness.

Also, let me know if you find a better way.